# Selectively disabling optimizations in Theano

Tags: theano

Is it possible to "protect" expressions from optimizations in Theano?

In a few places I'm relying on the fact that floating point numbers are not associative. For instance, I'm computing `(a - b) + b` and I don't want Theano to simplify it as `a`.

Is this possible without disabling optimizations entirely?

Comment: Either store intermediate values in shared variable, or wrap the expression to be protected in `OpFromGraph`. But I'm curious what kind of application requires strict FP here? Doesn't sounds like theano is the best tool for that.

Comment: @Kh40tiK Deep Learning. To know more, if everything goes well, you'll have to read my paper :)